# How to compare a key in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have structured my Firebase DB like this:

```
SOMETHING
    USERID (<- unique)
        TIMESTAMP  (<- unique within USERID)
            SOMETHING: 'something',
            SOMETHING: 'something'
```

How can I compare `USERID` to another `ID` in my code?

I have tried (with no luck - it returns a JSON with a lot of strange objects in it):

```
let id = 337462940
let exist = Firebase.database().ref(`SOMETHING/${id}`)

if (exist) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats happening because with `Firebase.database().ref('SOMETHING/${id}')` you only have the ref to the data. To actually retrieve it you nedd to use `.on` or `.once`.

```
Firebase.database().ref(`SOMETHING/${id}`).once('value', function(snapshot){
    var exists = snapshot.val();
    if (exists){
        console.log(exists);
    }
});
```

Make sure you read the [retrieving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data) section in firebase documentation to understand how querying data with firebase works.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/17/).

Comment: Thank you! Worked. Super cool that you created a jsFiddle to illustrate!